# How to redirect MVC app action calls to distant web api using IIS url rewrite

Tags: redirect, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, url-rewrite-module

I have a website (.net core, compiled all in dlls, i.e. no views, no javascript available to modify) which I don't have the source code (was made by someone else who's no longer reachable) and my client wants a single page on this website that makes an ajax call to an action of a controller in this same app to be redirected to a new web api method.

So, for example, this page (_http://the-old-site.com/Home/Index) have a form with a field and a button. Upon entering some values in the form's field and pressing the button, a POST ajax call is made to _http://the-old-site.com/Home/Process passing the value to the action.

I'm trying to configure the url rewrite module so that instead of calling _http://host.com/Home/Process, it posts to _http://new-api-I-did.com/Process

Right now, my rule looks like this but it's never hit:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="redirect to api" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="/Home/Process" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://new-api-I-did.com/Process" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

The api in itself works perfectly when testing it with Postman. 
Everything works except for the rewrite. And I tried both rewriting and redirecting.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Got the rule working but now, what's being sent in the redirection is an OPTIONS instead of a POST and the form's data aren't sent... Not sure how I can do this anymore.

Comment: The `OPTIONS` indicates there's a CORS pre-flight request. Did you forget to configure a CORS policy to allow this cross site request ?

Comment: I added "AllowedHosts": "*" for dev purposes, still not working

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what is "not working"? Do you still get the same `OPTIONS` ? If that's the case, how do you specify the `"AllowedHosts": "*"`? If not, could you please show the related response?